# Creating wide data that has only 1 ID column

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape, reshape2

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
  ID Code_Type Code date 
   1   10        4    1
   1    9        5    2
   2    10       6    3
   2    9        7    4
```

and I would like it to look like this:

```
  ID date.1 date.2  9  10
   1   1        2   5  4
   2   3        4   7  6
```

Where the different dates have different columns on the same row.

My current code is this:

```
#Example df
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,2,2), 
                 "Code_Type" = c(10,9,10,9), 
                 "Code" = c(4,5,6,7),
                 "date"= c(1,2,3,4))

spread(df, Code_Type,Code)
```

This outputs:

```
  ID date   9  10
   1   1    NA  4
   1   2    5  NA
   2   3    NA  6
   2   4    7  NA
```

Which is similar to what I want I just have no idea how to make the date column turn into multiple columns. Any help or extra reading is appreciated.

To clarify this is my expected output data frame

```
  ID date.1 date.2  9  10
   1   1        2   5  4
   2   3        4   7  6
```

Comment: Please add an example data frame of your expected output to your question.

Comment: It may not have been clear it is the second data frame I will edit for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reshape` from base R.

```
reshape(dat, idvar=c("ID"), timevar="Code_Type", direction="wide")
#   ID Code.10 date.10 Code.9 date.9
# 1  1       4       1      5      2
# 3  2       6       3      7      4
```

***Data***

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2), Code_Type = c(10, 9, 10, 9
), Code = c(4, 5, 6, 7), date = c(1, 2, 3, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: That does not create the wide data format where there is 1 ID and everything else is on that same row.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` / `tidyr` alternative:

```
df %>% mutate(date.1 = date %% 2 * date) %>% mutate(date.2 = - (date %% 2 - 1) * date) %>% select(-date) %>% spread(Code_Type, Code) %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_all(list(~ sum(.[!is.na(.)])))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
     ID date.1 date.2   `9`  `10`
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1      1      2     5     4
2     2      3      4     7     6
```

The idea is to split the `date` column into two columns whether `date` is *even* or *odd*. This is done using the modulo (`%%`) operator (and some additional number crunching). `date.1 = date %% 2 * date` catches the odd numbers in date and is `0` for all the others; `date.2 = - (date %% 2 - 1) * date` catches the even numbers and is `0` for all the others.

Afterwards it's straight forward: select all columns but `date`; spread it to wide format and, a bit tricky again, summarise by `ID` and drop all `NA`s (`group_by(ID) %>% summarise_all(list(~ sum(.[!is.na(.)])))`.

Comment: I get this error Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "list"
When I run it. Do you know what this is?

Comment: @DillonLloyd: No idea. It works over here.. I reformatted the code, maybe it was because of the `+` sign in it.. Does it work now?

Comment: Yes it does, however, I do not fully understand what you are doing in the mutate statements

Comment: @DillonLloyd: I made an edit with some explanations.